Creating Conditional Column based on another Table's Column
How do you create a new column based on values in another column in the same table and another column in a different table?
Example
Table 1:
| Index    | Part Description        |
| -------- | ----------------------- |
| 1        | Contain Leather Cushion |
| 2        | West Hill 72W Circuit   |
Table 2: "Model_Names"(Note: Replace column used in different process)



Name
Replace




Contain



West Hill




Result:



Index
Part Description
Make




1
Contain Leather Cushion
Contain


2
West Hill 72W Circuit
West Hill



Initally I was using if and elif functions to do the process however this is not an effective method.
I attempted using Code Below, however its currently only produces "Universal" and doesn't output any matching values:
make = Table.AddColumn(#"Multiplied Column1", "Make", each if List.Contains(Table.Column(Model_Names, "Name"), [Part Description]) then Table.Column(Model_Names, "Name") else "Universal")

Another Method I found to almost work just doesn't output correcrtly: However just need it to output the list values that are true: make = Table.AddColumn(#"Multiplied Column1", "Make", each if List.Transform(Table.Column(Model_Names, "Name"), (substring) => Text.Contains([Part Description], substring)) then [Name] else "Universal")

Here's a suggestion:

In this example Table4 is the one with Part Description
For each description, loop through the model names and use the first match (or default)
May not be the most efficient way, but would work

let 
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table4"]}[Content],

    modelNames = List.Buffer(Model_Names[Name]),
    makeList = List.Transform(Source[Part Description], (descr) =>
        try List.Select(modelNames, each Text.Contains(descr, _)){0} otherwise "Universal"),
        
    columns = Table.ToColumns(Source) & {makeList}, 
    headers = Table.ColumnNames(Source) & {"Make"},
    addedMake = Table.FromColumns(columns, headers)
 in
    addedMake



Thank you so much. I'm not very proficient in power query yet, and this problem has been a headache trying to figure out.

You're most welcome! I also started using it earlier this year and like it very much.
